# Account validation by an administrator with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using rails again after a few months idling, and I need to set up a simple authentification solution for which I intend to use devise. However, I don't want anybody to be able to create an account - I want the accounts to be locked until I confirm they are legit.

Unless I'm wrong, devise doesn't come bundled with this kind of module. Is there a solution like this one available somewhere I haven't found ?

An alternative solution would be to use a white list. I'd set up a base of authorized emails and validates on that. It seems doable enough, but is there any issues with white lists that I don't see ?

thanks for you time guys!